# Using TypeScript on a simple vue 3 form

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am having the hardest time understanding how to use TypeScript in my Vue 3 composition api project.  I have looked at tutorials and I'm even on a project using it but something is not clicking for me and I'm not sure why.  I think what would help me is to create my own vue 3 composition api app with the stack overflow communities help.

I have a simple application to track books that I read or plan to read.  Here are just a few fields:

1. Name of Book
2. Name of Author
3. Total Pages
4. Read Completed

Can someone please help me to understand how I would use TypeScript with this form?  This may seem very basic for you but I'm just trying to understand.  I will ask more questions as I build out my book tracker.

Here's my [repo](https://github.com/ilatine/book-tracker)
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `reactive`

```js
type BookForm = {
    name: string;
    author: string;
    totalPages: number;
    read: boolean;
}

const form = reactive<BookForm>({
    name: '',
    author: '',
    totalPages: 0,
    read: false,
});
```

or, you can break it out into separate `refs`

```js
const name = ref(''); // types are automatically inferred
const author = ref('');
const totalPages = ref(0);
const read = ref(false);
```

you can explicitly set type for refs too

```js
const book = ref<Book>(); // book will have a type of Book | undefined
```

Comment: How can I use an interface and where would I add it?  I added a link to my repo.